# A Docking station that would work for Macbook And Alienware

Tags: macbook-pro, docking-station

I have a macbook pro 13" and an alienware 15" that I would like to be able to swap external monitors, mouse and keyboard quickly. At the moment this requires some unplugging and replugging. However, I was looking for a solution that would enable me to be able to use one plug (USB?) for both machines.

Other than a docking station I was looking at something like the [Dell P2715Q](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&sku=210-ADOF) which has some USB outputs which I think would possibly work but I wanted to check what the preferred method is for this (or is it just a case of 2 docking stations/ unplugging and replugging lots of things in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These devices will often be referred to as a kvm switch or a display switch. There are industrial grade and home grade versions of these devices, the main difference being the number of devices the hardware can use.

These switches generally have input buttons that allow you to switch between PC1, PC2, ect, while sharing a common display and set of peripherals. Most of these devices come with ports for USB, PS2, ect.

While you're researching this question, I wouldn't get confused with the term "docking station". These are typically devices that are dedicated to docking a single, specific brand/model laptop or tablet (although not the case with some USB "docking stations" and other exceptions).

[image]

Comment: That's great. One questions, any idea on a KVM switch that would suit the specs I mentioned?

Comment: Superuser is great for asking hardware related questions, but the rules don't allow me to answer this question with a specific piece of hardware: `"asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation"`. It should be easy to find a device compatible, these devices normally don't care about the OS. It's all about the physical connections (requiring VGA, HDMI, ect).

Comment: no problems. Thanks for your input I'm sure I can take it from here (1st question on superuser).